# Webdriver getText() of an element returns blank

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have an element with a dynamic number. It's a unique order number that gets generated after every order. I am trying to fetch that number from a paragraph, `<p>` tag using the getText() method, but webdriver returns a blank text after the test is run.

Executing :

```
boolean a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@id='alert-message']/div/p/strong)[1]")).isDisplayed();
```

returns false, suggesting the element is not displayed.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-include="templates[step]">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="wReviewCtrl">
<div class="panel-alert ng-hide" ng-show="success<0">
<div class="panel-alert" ng-show="success>0 && hasRole('BUYER')">
<div class="alert-wrap in">
<div id="alert-message" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<div class="media">
<strong>Done!</strong>
<p>
A new order with Number
<strong class="ng-binding">JJ-MD000-12345</strong>  //Order number
 was generated. The order is now complete.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-alert ng-hide" ng-show="success>0 && hasRole('SELLER')">
<div class="alert-wrap in">
<div id="alert-message" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<div class="media">
<strong>Done!</strong>
<p>
```

I tried getting text using:

```
String orderNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@id='alert-message']/div/p/strong)[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(orderNo);
```

I have tried all sorts of alternative combinations instead of `.getText()` including:

```
.getAttribute("textContent");
.getAttribute("innerHTML");
.getAttribute("value");  //retuns NULL value
.getAttribute("outerText");
```

But none of them worked. How can I get that order number in the HTML?

Comment: Try to get the innerHTML property of  p and see if the html has the required value. It might be possible that you are trying to read value out of it before angular has updated the bindings . You can verify this by adding delay of 10-15 seconds ...If it works you can consider using a better approach such as explicit wait conditions of webdriver with condition on visibility (should be true).

Comment: Thanks, @Nish26. Getting the whole of the texts in the p tag does work, and I got an output of: "A new order with Number JJ-MD000-12345 was generated. The order is now complete." My intention is to get the order number only and this the one that returns blank. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nish, I cracked it and your tip led to the resolution. The explicit wait condition works. If you put the answer in the answer box, I can mark it as the official answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using explicit waits and check for element to become visible. Once the popup opens, you are trying to access the text before angular has a chance to update the binding. As a result you are getting empty text.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting the whole of the texts in the p tag does work, and I got an
>   output of: "A new order with Number JJ-MD000-12345 was generated. The
>   order is now complete." My intention is to get the order number only
>   and this the one that returns blank. Any ideas?

I would suggest the following if only the order number is dynamic:

```
String s = "A new order with Number JJ-MD000-12345 was generated. The order is now complete."; // is the string, which you are getting from 'p' tag
String[] parts = s.split(" "); // split this string to parts
String output = parts[5]; // choose the part with your order number
System.out.println(output); // JJ-MD000-12345
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the desired element is an *Angular* element so you can induce *WebDriverWait* with *ExpectedConditions* set as [**`attributeToBeNotEmpty()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#attributeToBeNotEmpty-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.String-) and then extract/print the **dynamic value** as per the following code block :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBeNotEmpty(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success' and @id='alert-message']/div[@class='media']//p//strong[@class='ng-binding']")), "innerHTML"));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success' and @id='alert-message']/div[@class='media']//p//strong[@class='ng-binding']")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```